# QGIS attribute form table of contents highlighting is missing

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

When in form view in the attribute table, QGIS displays a "table of contents" beside the form, which *usually* highlights the feature being displayed in the form. Example:

[image: Example working fine]

In two of my layers, somehow that highlight does not show. Example: (the row directly beside `LongLabel` should be highlighted).

[image: Faulty example]

Any idea what setting I've munged somewhere, and how to fix it?

The TOC is set to display a virtual field, but the problem on those layers doesn't get fixed if I use a regular field or a custom expression. I do have conditional formatting conditions (and they work), but the problem persists when I remove them too. The form is Drag and Drop rather than autogenerate, but I can't imagine drag and drop wouldn't allow highlighting, and I think it worked previously.

(Using QGIS Win 3.12, but this has been going on for some time and with several 3.x versions, I just haven't had time to try to fix it.)

Comment: That most likely sounds like a bug. Have you considered submitting an issue on the tracker https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new/choose ? Or can you share a demo project?

Comment: An Issue has been created (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34628) and there is a workaround described there.